# NoMethodError: undefined method `ignore' for Warning:Module

Tags: ruby, testing, ruby-on-rails-4

I am unable to find any explanation for this error but when I am running:
`rake test` or `bundle exec rake test` I am getting:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `ignore' for Warning:Module
/Users/przemyslaw/projects/writefully/config/initializers/warning.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/przemyslaw/projects/writefully/config/initializers/warning.rb:3:in `each'
/Users/przemyslaw/projects/writefully/config/initializers/warning.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/przemyslaw/projects/writefully/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/przemyslaw/projects/writefully/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `require'
/Users/przemyslaw/projects/writefully/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/przemyslaw/projects/writefully/test/controllers/comments_controller_test.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/przemyslaw/projects/writefully/test/controllers/comments_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:run
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am following a tutorial on codemy.net and there is nothing complicated or special about this project. I have only generated a new rails app, a couple of models and controllers and now when I am trying to run the test it gives me this error. There is no single test within my test files at the moment so this is nothing to do with testing. It looks like there is some issue with the 'ignore' method within the warning file:

*config/initializers/warning.rb*

```
# Rails will load this logic before booting up Rails server
unless Rails.env.development?
  Gem.path.each do |path|
    Warning.ignore(//, path)
  end
end
```

Any help or idea would be appreciated. I am using rails 4.2.10 and ruby 2.5.8.

Comment: Did you install the `warning` gem and how did you do that? What version did you install? Did you require the gem or do you use bundler?

Comment: I did not install the `warning` gem and I am using bundler, but there is no `warning` gem within the Gemfile nor `require 'warning'` anywhere within my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you missed installing the [`warning` gem](https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-warning).

I suggest adding the line

```
gem "warning"
```

to your `Gemfile` and run `bundler` before restarting your application.

Comment: Thank you so much @spickerman. I am surprised this gem isn't included by default within the Gemfile if it causes this issue.

Comment: @Pshemski: The version you chose to use is unsupported. It it not surprising that a tutorials which tells you to use outdated, unsupported, unmaintained versions would have other bugs as well, don't you think?

Comment: I suppose you are right @JörgWMittag. A rookie mistake from my side ;)